# How do I create a web front end to access a Postgres database behind-the-scenes?

Tags: php, database, apache, postgresql, authentication

I have PHP, Apache web server and Postgres installed on a CentOS 7.3 server. PHP works independently. Apache web server works indepedently. Postgres works independently.

I created a PHP script to authenticate to a Postgres database.  But it is not presented to the user via a web browser.  This file does not accept user input.

I want to create a web page that accepts a username and password and authenticates into the Postgres database. I have various Postgres credentials. How do I create a web page to have the user gain access to the Postgres database (e.g., server-side, backend authentication)?

I want users to access the database from a web front end. I want authenticated users to run searches from the website. These searches will be supported by select statements behind-the-scenes. Maybe I do not need Apache web server.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand from your rough message, I can give you some rough advices:

1. You need Apache or nginx webserver to serve PHP server pages to a client's web browser
2. You can create a simple login interface and authenticate to PostgreSQL using the following function:
   http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-connect.php
   The function returns FALSE on logon failure.
3. If the function returns TRUE, you will need:

   a/ save user credentials to a $_SESSION or to PHP_AUTH

   b/ display a simple interface to users to run searches

   c/ on the backend it will be custom SQL commands with user "search" inputs", such as SELECT * FROM products WHERE name LIKE '%whatever%'

   d/ and display results from database into a simple HTML table.

   e/ remember to escape search queries - XSS prevention :)

Comment: How do I do 3a?